# MAC address randomization

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address

I have some kind of problem. Im trying to make auto light switcher, when me or one of my family members come home.I have an esp8266 nearly situated to my house and sniffing MAC addresses of people, coming close with WI-Fi switched on. But i have problem: while my phone not connected to the network, it randoms MAC address, and in the start i have da:a1:19...

Here it is my real address 50:8f:4c:54:38:52
and the fake one: da:a1:19:ca:6e:48

Any ideas how to decode fake MAC to real?

Answer (score 1):

The 'fake' one is truly random. There is nothing to decode.

It will only switch to its 'real' MAC address when it establishes a secure connection to a previously authorised device. This is intentional, to prevent tracking.

From Source:Android - [Privacy: MAC Randomization](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization)
iMore - [What's really happening with iOS 8 MAC address randomization?](https://www.imore.com/closer-look-ios-8s-mac-randomization)

Comment: i've got an info that some companies, producing wi-fi radars, came up with some algorithm that finds out correct MAC. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Apparently, the implementation in Android was a waste of time & most phones don't even have it enabled. Android 9 may fix that, but as most android users never update their OS, it's probably still trivial to track most device's address. https://www.zdnet.com/article/android-q-to-get-a-ton-of-new-privacy-features/